# Q: Is Analytics for Apache Hadoop still available on Bluemix? (Not in my catalog for any geo)

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

I'm looking for the Analytics for Apache Hadoop service in Bluemix to try out SystemT Text Analytics for a project I'm working on. It seems like it's not available any more. It this the case? Is there any replacement or is the service just discontinued?

Documentation for the service is available in Bluemix docs, but it doesn't show up in the catalog no matter what geography I choose.

Answer (score 1):

The Analytics for Apache Hadoop service on Bluemix has been decommissioned on February 22, 2016. Based on user feedback, IBM is building an enhanced version of this service with an improved architecture. You can register for that BETA [here](http://www2.cloudant.com/biginsights-on-cloud-paygo-beta).

Answer (score 1):

To add to Umberto's answer:

We announced the removal of the Analytics for Apache Hadoop service on January 29th on the [Bluemix Status Page](http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus). Here is a copy of the announcement:

**Announcement: Analytics for Apache Hadoop service to be decommissioned**

The Analytics for Apache Hadoop service will be decommissioned on February 22, 2016.

You must save any data or other artifacts from your instance. Data and artifacts will not be accessible after Feb 22, 2016 as they will be deleted.

Based on customer and trial user feedback, we are building an enhanced version of this service. You can register for the new Beta version at the link below.

**Updated:**   Jan 29, 2016 9:01 AM UTC-0600
**Starts:**    Jan 29, 2016 10:00 AM UTC-0600
**Category:**  Analytics for Apache Hadoop
**Region(s):** us-south
**More info:** http://www2.cloudant.com/biginsights-on-cloud-paygo-beta